# Как поменять тип данных макроса в qt?

Tags: qt, макросы, макрос

В общем подключил код для работы с протоколом КАН.
НО появилась ошибка не получается задать тип данных, точнее стандартное создание переменной к примеру: BYTE qwerty; WORD ytrewq; и т.д. А конструкция приведенная ниже не как не реагирует (не видит типы данных и Qt редактор не выделяет тип данных в самой конструкции).

Заголовочный файл PCANBasic.h

```
#ifndef __PCANBASICH__
#define __PCANBASICH__

#include <QtGlobal>

 // Начало, после заголовка 
typedef unsigned short WORD; // хмм ок
typedef unsigned long int DWORD; // хмм ок
typedef unsigned char BYTE;  //ок
typedef char CHAR;
typedef CHAR *LPSTR;
// ---

.....

// Код не работает, фактически он не видит типы данных BYTE  DWORD WORD  
//#define TPCANHandle              BYTE  // Represents a PCAN hardware channel handle
//#define TPCANStatus              DWORD // Represents a PCAN status/error code
//#define TPCANParameter           BYTE  // Represents a PCAN parameter to be read or set
//#define TPCANDevice              BYTE  // Represents a PCAN device
//#define TPCANMessageType         BYTE  // Represents the type of a PCAN message
//#define TPCANType                BYTE  // Represents the type of PCAN hardware to be initialized
//#define TPCANMode                BYTE  // Represents a PCAN filter mode
//#define TPCANBaudrate            WORD  // Represents a PCAN Baud rate register value

// вставил код на qt (тоже не работает)
#define TPCANHandle        uchar  // Represents a PCAN hardware channel handle
#define TPCANStatus        ulong  // Represents a PCAN status/error code
#define TPCANParameter     uchar  // Represents a PCAN parameter to be read or set
#define TPCANDevice        uchar  // Represents a PCAN device
#define TPCANMessageType   uchar  // Represents the type of a PCAN message
#define TPCANType          uchar  // Represents the type of PCAN hardware to be initialized
#define TPCANMode          uchar  // Represents a PCAN filter mode
#define TPCANBaudrate      ushort // Represents a PCAN Baud rate register value
// ---
```

Выдаёт ошибку что TPCANStatus и другие не видят: ulong, uchar, ushort (редактор не подсвечивает)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Незнаю считаеться ли это за ответ или нет, но  я просто отказался от этой конструкции и напрямую прописал в коде (вот часть его (где как раз происходит вызов функций)) :

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PCAN-Basic API function declarations
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/// <summary>
/// Initializes a PCAN Channel 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <param name="Btr0Btr1">"The speed for the communication (BTR0BTR1 code)"</param>
/// <param name="HwType">"NON PLUG&PLAY: The type of hardware and operation mode"</param>
/// <param name="IOPort">"NON PLUG&PLAY: The I/O address for the parallel port"</param>
/// <param name="Interupt">"NON PLUG&PLAY: Interrupt number of the parallel port"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_Initialize(
//        TPCANHandle Channel,
DWORD __stdcall CAN_Initialize(
        BYTE Channel,
        WORD Btr0Btr1,
//        TPCANBaudrate Btr0Btr1,
//        TPCANType HwType _DEF_ARG,
        BYTE HwType _DEF_ARG,
        DWORD IOPort _DEF_ARG, 
        WORD Interrupt _DEF_ARG);


/// <summary>
/// Uninitializes one or all PCAN Channels initialized by CAN_Initialize
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Giving the TPCANHandle value "PCAN_NONEBUS", 
/// uninitialize all initialized channels</remarks>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_Uninitialize(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_Uninitialize(
//        TPCANHandle Channel);
        BYTE Channel);


/// <summary>
/// Resets the receive and transmit queues of the PCAN Channel  
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// A reset of the CAN controller is not performed.
/// </remarks>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_Reset(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_Reset(
//        TPCANHandle Channel);
        BYTE Channel);


/// <summary>
/// Gets the current status of a PCAN Channel 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_GetStatus(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_GetStatus(
//        TPCANHandle Channel);
        BYTE Channel);


/// <summary>
/// Reads a CAN message from the receive queue of a PCAN Channel 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <param name="MessageBuffer">"A TPCANMsg structure buffer to store the CAN message"</param>
/// <param name="TimestampBuffer">"A TPCANTimestamp structure buffer to get 
/// the reception time of the message. If this value is not desired, this parameter
/// should be passed as NULL"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_Read(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_Read(
//        TPCANHandle Channel,
        BYTE Channel,
        TPCANMsg* MessageBuffer, 
        TPCANTimestamp* TimestampBuffer);


/// <summary>
/// Transmits a CAN message 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <param name="MessageBuffer">"A TPCANMsg buffer with the message to be sent"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_Write(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_Write(
//        TPCANHandle Channel,
        BYTE Channel,
        TPCANMsg* MessageBuffer);


/// <summary>
/// Configures the reception filter. 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The message filter will be expanded with every call to 
/// this function. If it is desired to reset the filter, please use 
/// the CAN_SetValue function</remarks>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <param name="FromID">"The lowest CAN ID to be received"</param>
/// <param name="ToID">"The highest CAN ID to be received"</param>
/// <param name="Mode">"Message type, Standard (11-bit identifier) or 
/// Extended (29-bit identifier)"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_FilterMessages(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_FilterMessages(
//        TPCANHandle Channel,
        BYTE Channel,
        DWORD FromID, 
        DWORD ToID, 
//        TPCANMode Mode);
        BYTE Mode);


/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a PCAN Channel value
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Parameters can be present or not according with the kind 
/// of Hardware (PCAN Channel) being used. If a parameter is not available,
/// a PCAN_ERROR_ILLPARAMTYPE error will be returned</remarks>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <param name="Parameter">"The TPCANParameter parameter to get"</param>
/// <param name="Buffer">"Buffer for the parameter value"</param>
/// <param name="BufferLength">"Size in bytes of the buffer"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_GetValue(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_GetValue(
//        TPCANHandle Channel,
        BYTE Channel,
//        TPCANParameter Parameter,
        BYTE Parameter,
        void* Buffer, 
        DWORD BufferLength);


/// <summary>
/// Configures or sets a PCAN Channel value 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Parameters can be present or not according with the kind 
/// of Hardware (PCAN Channel) being used. If a parameter is not available,
/// a PCAN_ERROR_ILLPARAMTYPE error will be returned</remarks>
/// <param name="Channel">"The handle of a PCAN Channel"</param>
/// <param name="Parameter">"The TPCANParameter parameter to set"</param>
/// <param name="Buffer">"Buffer with the value to be set"</param>
/// <param name="BufferLength">"Size in bytes of the buffer"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_SetValue(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_SetValue(
//        TPCANHandle Channel,
        BYTE Channel,
//        TPCANParameter Parameter,
        BYTE Parameter,
        void* Buffer,
        DWORD BufferLength);


/// <summary>
/// Returns a descriptive text of a given TPCANStatus error 
/// code, in any desired language
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The current languages available for translation are: 
/// Neutral (0x00), German (0x07), English (0x09), Spanish (0x0A),
/// Italian (0x10) and French (0x0C)</remarks>
/// <param name="Error">"A TPCANStatus error code"</param>
/// <param name="Language">"Indicates a 'Primary language ID'"</param>
/// <param name="Buffer">"Buffer for a null terminated char array"</param>
/// <returns>"A TPCANStatus error code"</returns>
//TPCANStatus __stdcall CAN_GetErrorText(
DWORD __stdcall CAN_GetErrorText(
//        TPCANStatus Error,
        DWORD Error,
        WORD Language, 
        LPSTR Buffer);
```